# Generating a main script and a some libraries/modules with Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to build a web application made one main entry point (`index.js`) and a number of modules that I want to load dynamically.

Something like:

###### index.js

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', async function(){
  const mod = await import('module1.js');
  mod.run();
});
```

###### module1.js

```
export function run() {
  console.log("Hello from module1");
}
```

Is it possible to build a bundle for each of these files using Webpack 5?

#### What I tried

###### output.library (but it builds *everything* as libraries)

1. It seems that Webpack lets me set multiple [entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).
2. However to expose all of `module1.js`'s exports [I need to set output.library](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/).
3. But if I do, then `index.js` is built as a library too, since [there can be only one output field](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/).

###### Multiple configurations (but it breaks the dev server)

I could configure Webpack to build both my main script and the modules using [multiple configurations](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations), but if I try this, then the webpack-dev-server tries to start two instances and fails.

It prints errors like:

> `<e> [webpack-dev-middleware] ConcurrentCompilationError: You ran Webpack twice. Each instance only supports a single concurrent compilation at a time.`

#### What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer: the correct way to do this is to use a dynamic import. By default Webpack places the dynamically-imported resource in different files.

More documentation:

- [Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting)
- [Lazy Loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/)
- [Dynamic expressions in import()](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).